# What does HashMap(Map m) constructor does?

Tags: java, hashmap

I  have come across a piece of code where I found

```
  public class MapImpl {
   private static MapImpl mpl = new MapImpl();
     Map<String,String> hm;
     private MapImpl() {
          hm = new HashMap<>();
       }
     public addContentsToMap(Map<String,String> m){
         this.hm=m;
     }
     public Map returnMap(){
         new HashMap<>(hm);
       }
    }
```

I like to know here that when the default constructor is called the map is initialized to hashmap, and when addContentsToMap is called a map is formed with values.

I see that the returnMap uses the constructor of the HashMap(Map m). I have gone through the source code of HashMap but was clueless.

Comment: Constructs a new HashMap with the same mappings as the specified Map. The HashMap is created with default load factor (0.75) and an initial capacity sufficient to hold the mappings in the specified Map.

Comment: Did you look up [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-)? I'm not sure what you're unclear about.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap(java.util.Map)

Comment: When you see a constructor which takes the same class as argument, it is often a constructor by copy. Moreover and like the others said : what don't you understand in the javadoc?

Comment: @MuratK. Might want to point the OP to the page you copied that from. Teach a person to fish, and all that. (Also because citing sources is generally good.)

Comment: Perhaps you are wondering why someone would want to use this constructor.  Well, a person could have a different implementation of `Map`, e.g. `TreeMap`, but now for whatever reason they want to proceed with that data as a `HashMap`.  Well, this copy constructor is one way to do that.  Rather than having to iterate, Collections exposes a convenience constructor for this.

Comment: @all_asking_me_what_I_didn't_get_from_javadocs: I have gone through the compiled source code, from eclipse. I was not able to get the code after looking over it.

Comment: `public class MapImpl {
   private static MapImpl mpl = new MapImpl();`
- Won't that cause a stack overflow?

Comment: I am creating a singleton object here of MapImpl

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that the field `mpl` is static.

Comment: So, is your question about what the constructor does, or how it does it? If you're just asking what it does, you shouldn't need the source code at all -- the javadoc explains that. If you're asking how it accomplishes that goal, presumably for the purpose of learning from it, then you'll need to clarify what specifically you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes any implementation of `Map` interface and constructs a `HashMap` which also is an implementation of `Map` interface.

Developers like Hash-Collections (`HashSet`, `HashMap` etc.) including `HashMap` because they provide expected `O(1)` get and contains time.

It can be useful, once you have a `Map` which isn't a `HashMap` (e.g. `Properties`) and you know that it'll be large and you will read from it many times, it's useful to switch to a different implementation of a `Map`.

[Documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-)

> `public HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)`
>
> Constructs a new HashMap with the same mappings as the specified Map. The HashMap is created with default load factor (0.75) and an initial capacity sufficient to hold the mappings in the specified Map.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `m` - the map whose mappings are to be placed in this map
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the specified map is null

Comment: @yshavit it's because it's general programming concept - in technical writing, you should always use technical font for such things.

Comment: @xenteros fwiw, I think that's likely to confuse people. Backticks are for [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) specifically (not "general programming concepts" blocks), which I think most people would take to mean code snippets, specific class or method names, etc.